# Android notifyDataSetChanged on SimpleAdapter loses focus

Tags: android

I have a EditText view and SimpleAdapter based ListView, on some data change I am calling notifyDataSetChanged  on adapter which causes EditText view to lose focus, I tried calling requestFocus to get focus back on text field but it is not working. How can I get focus back ?

Comment: Provide your code please

Comment: Can you please post the code?